Override swipe back for PageView
How can I override swipe back so that it takes me back to the previous page in pagView?
I have next architecture:
Page A -> 
   Page B {
   PageView[Pages]
   }

Page B build mehtod:
    return BlocBuilder<EstimationBloc, EstimationState>(
      builder: (context, estimationState) {
        final request = estimationState.estimationRequest;
        _checkFields(screens[estimationState.currentStep - 1]);
        final int totalSteps = screens.length - 1;
        final isLastPage = estimationState.currentStep == screens.length;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    onPageChanged: (index) {
                      _setStep(index + 1);
                    },
                    controller: _pageViewController,
                    children: [
                      WidgetA,
                      WidgetB,
                      WidgetC,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

When i swipe back on Page B, i just return on page A. Can I override swipe at all?
For navigation i use goRouter, and on Page B i navigate with goName. If i wrap Page B's scaffold in PopScope, it wont initiate onPopInvoked, when i swaping back.
But it calls only when i press back button in appBar to return on Page A.
